# Critique wanted on JS

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to re-learn some JS fundamentals and wondered if anyone knowledgabe could tell me if I'm doing something very wrong in my approach to this simple word counting class.

I want to create a class that takes arbitrary text and returns information about its wordcount, frequency of words, etc. One of the methods I have so far returns a hash where each key coresponding to a word has an element called count which is its frequency in the text.

One usage is to produce an output that will be printed to a file with WORD COUNT on each line.

```
function WordCounter(){
   this.text = new String()
}

WordCounter.prototype.addWords = function(words){
    this.text += words
}

WordCounter.prototype.count = function(){
    return this.text.split(" ").length
}
WordCounter.prototype.getFrequenciesAsHash = function(){
    var words = this.text.split(" ")
    var frequencies = {}
    while(words.length > 0){
        var word = words.pop()
    if(typeof frequencies[word] == "undefined"){
        frequencies[word] = {}
        frequencies[word].count = 0
    }
    frequencies[word].count++
    }
    return frequencies
}
```

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to do really...

Comment: Thanks for looking. I guess I could have described better. I want to create a class that takes arbitrary text and returns information about its wordcount, frequency of words, etc. One of the methods I have so far returns a hash where each key coresponding to a word has an element called count which is its frequency in the text.

Comment: @maninjeans: Go ahead and edit that into the question for everyone else to see.

Comment: @jamal man you guys are fast, edited in as you typed :)

Comment: @maninjeans: I have a lot of free time. :-)

Comment: `WordCounter.prototype.getFrequenciesAsHash` ... `return words.split(" ").reduce(function(a,b){ a[b] ? a[b]++ : a[b] = 1; return a;},{});`

Comment: ``"        ".split(" ")`` -> ``['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']``. Probably not what you want.

Answer (score 3):

Conceptually, I feel like you are doing this backwards. You should be storing an array of strings instead of repeatedly splitting a string into an array.

Here's my take on it:

```
function WordCounter(){
   this.words = []; // You should just use an array. It makes more sense here.
}

WordCounter.prototype.addWords = function(){
    // this allows you to pass in words as multiple arguments, or as an array of words
    // i.e.: 
    // myWordCounter.addWords(["one","two","three"]); 
    // or 
    // myWordCounter.addWords("one", "two", "three");
    this.words = this.words.concat([].slice.call(arguments));
}
WordCounter.prototype.count = function(){
    return this.words.length;
}
WordCounter.prototype.toString = function(){
    //this replaces the text property
    return this.words.join(" ");
}
WordCounter.prototype.getFrequenciesAsHash = function(){
    // reduce is much more elegant here. 
    // if you have to support older browsers, just use a shim to fill in array method support
    return this.words.reduce(function(hash, word){
        // no need to do a typeof.
        if(hash[word] === undefined) 
            hash[word] = 0; // no reason to create an object

        hash[word]++;

        return hash;
    }, {});
}
```

If you want to be able to add words from a multi-word string, I would suggest a separate method for clarity:

```
WordCounter.prototype.extractWords = function(string){
    this.addWords(string.match(/\w+/g));
}
```

The naming could be better.

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking the same thing yesterday, that I sould maintain an array of strings instead of creating one each time the getFrequencies is called, but I was unsure how to best go about it. The reduce method also seems to be the way to go. I'll play around with this tonight.